Linear regression model to errors in variables
I made a regression model like this:
$\mathbf{U}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}+\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$. Here, $\mathbf{A}$ is an unknown $d_u$ by $d_x$ matrix and $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$ is $d_u$ by 1 random vector and $\mathbf{U}$ is a $d_u$ by $1$ random vector. Here, $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{X}$ are covariates.With this regression model constraint, I want to make errors in variables model:
$$\tilde{\mathbf{U}}_i=\mathbf{U}_i+\tilde{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}_i $$
for $i=1, \cdots n$, where $\tilde{\mathbf{U}}:=\mathbf{AX}$ and $\tilde{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}:=-\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$. For usual errors in variables setting, I want to assume that $\mathbf{U}_i \in [0,1]^{d_u}$ and $\mathbf{U}_i$ and $\tilde{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}_i$ are independnet. Is it fine to assume like that?

Your model is grossly underdetermined: you have only $d_u$ observations but $d_ud_x$ parameters to estimate.  How do you hope to do that?  Introducing errors in variables further complicates this basic problem.
